# Load dynamic delegate function from text file?

Tags: c#

I wana write dynamic delegate function, look like this

```
public delegate int functionX(int a, int b);
functionX = loadFunction(textFile); // the loadFunction is function i wana write.
```

So i wana change text file dynamic to have dynamic delegate function. Ex: text file like this, i will have **functionX** like **Add** function.

```
int Add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Or have **functionX** like **Subtract** function and ect...

```
int Subtract(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank for help @Kell. i wana to write cheat dynamic cheat for my game load from file. ^-^

Comment: and thank @dymanoid!

Comment: i will delete it after some hours.

Comment: you don't have to delete your question. it will be marked as duplicate. but that doesn't mean this is not a good question. it may help others in future.